# How to change edited user to input with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have some problems. Firstly i made simple project with html/jquery. I have simple register form and user list.

after people sign my sites i want edit user's name, username and etc. only remain edit part. sorry my useless english. but when you see code i am sure you will understand.

this is code's. [codepen](https://codepen.io/akagamina/pen/KeyYOb)

```js
var userList = [];

var config = {
    date: {
        day: "2-digit",
        year: "numeric",
        month: "long",
        hour: "numeric",
        minute: "2-digit"
    }
}

var generateGUID = () => {
    var s4 = () => {
        return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
            .toString(16)
            .substring(1);
    }
    return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + s4() + s4();
}

var generateRow = user => `<tr data-info='${JSON.stringify(user)}' >
        <td>
        ${user.name}
        </td>
        <td>
        ${user.surname}
        </td>
        <td>
        ${user.email}
        </td>
        <td>
        ${user.username}
        </td>
        <td>
        ${user.createDate.toLocaleDateString("tr", config.date)}
        </td>
        <td>
            <button data-user="${user.id}" class="del">Del</button>
            <button data-user="${user.id}" class="edit">Edit</button>
        </td>
    </tr>`;



$("#button").click(() => {
    let user = {
        name: $('#name').val(),
        surname: $('#surname').val(),
        email: $('#email').val(),
        username: $('#username').val(),
        createDate: new Date(),
        id: generateGUID()
    };

    userList.push(user);
    $('#name').val('');
    $('#surname').val('');
    $('#email').val('');
    $('#username').val('');
    $('#password').val('');
    let row = $(generateRow(user));

    $(row).find(".del").click(function () {
        if (window.confirm("Do you really want to delete?")) {
            $(row).remove();
        }
    });

    $(row).find(".edit").click(function () {
        $("#edit").show();
        $("#button").hide();
        let edit = $(this).closest('tr').data('info');
        $('#name').val(edit.name);
        $('#surname').val(edit.surname);
        $('#email').val(edit.email);
        $('#username').val(edit.username);
        $(this).attr("data-user");
        $(userList).filter("data-user");

        $('#edit').click(function () {
        });
    });



    $('tbody').append(row);

});
```

```html
<html lang="tr">

<head>
    <!-- Standard Meta -->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">

    <!-- Site Properties -->
    <title>Bootstrap 4 Register Form</title>

    <!-- Stylesheets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="/register">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h2>Register New User</h2>
                    <hr>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 field-label-responsive">
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
                            <div class="input-group-addon" style="width: 2.6rem">
                                <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                            </div>
                            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="John or Jane" required autofocus>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 field-label-responsive">
                    <label for="email">Surname</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
                            <div class="input-group-addon" style="width: 2.6rem">
                                <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                            </div>
                            <input type="text" name="surname" class="form-control" id="surname" placeholder="Doe" required autofocus>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 field-label-responsive">
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
                            <div class="input-group-addon" style="width: 2.6rem">
                                <i class="fa fa-at"></i>
                            </div>
                            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="you@example.com" required autofocus>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 field-label-responsive">
                    <label for="password">Username</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group has-danger">
                        <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
                            <div class="input-group-addon" style="width: 2.6rem">
                                <i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i>
                            </div>
                            <input type="text" name="password" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Username" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 field-label-responsive">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group has-danger">
                        <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
                            <div class="input-group-addon" style="width: 2.6rem">
                                <i class="fa fa-key"></i>
                            </div>
                            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <button type="button" id="button" class="btn btn-success">
                        <i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i>Register</button>
                    <button type="button" style="display:none;" id="edit" class="btn btn-success">
                        Düzenle</button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Surname</th>
            <th scope="col">Email</th>
            <th scope="col">Username</th>
            <th scope="col">Register Date</th>
            <th scope="col">Edit</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>

<script src="script.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: You didn't tell us what the problem is? Please explain what is not working and how do you intend it to work.

Comment: when i click edit button. user's shows in input. this work now. i want when i click ''düzenle'' edited user goes to row.

Answer (score 0):

You could assign each user a unique Id and store that id along with user data inside userList array, so when edit button is clicked you can find that specific user using that id from the userList array and update the details.